# css margin-right is not working in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

margin-right property is not working exactly in Firefox as it is working in Chrome...
i m using margin-right between images but images are overlapping from its border. In Firefox margin-right should be twice of the margin-right used in Chrome..

Answer (score 0):

Does this has anything to do with border-box, because you said border:
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Or provide us with a jsfiddle etc. with the HTML / CSS.

Comment: Then provide us with some HTML / CSS so we can see the problem. The question is not really clear and also depends on doctype etc.